# Como somar a diagonal principal de uma matriz em python?

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo e quero saber se existe algum comando para somar a diagonal principal de uma matriz no Python

Comment: No Python, não, mas é uma operação trivial de ser implementada. Por que não tenta fazê-la você mesmo e poste aqui caso não conseguir?

Comment: obrigado, já consegui

Answer (score 4):

No Python não há uma função própria para tal, mas implementá-la é bastante trivial.

Uma matriz quadrada n x n pode ser representada como:

```
| (1, 1)   (1, 2)   (1, 3)   ...   (1, n) |
| (2, 1)   (2, 2)   (2, 3)   ...   (2, n) |
| (3, 1)   (3, 2)   (3, 3)   ...   (3, n) |
|  ...      ...      ...     ...    ...   |
| (n, 1)   (n, 2)   (n, 3)   ...   (n, n) |
```

Onde a diagonal principal é composta por: (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), ..., (n, n); ou seja, todos os valores na posição (i, j) em que i = j.

Assim, como o índice no Python inicia em 0, você precisa percorrer de 0 a n-1, sendo n o tamanho da matriz.

```
def soma_diagonal_principal(matriz):
    n = len(matriz)
    assert n == len(matriz[0]), 'Matriz precisa ser quadrada'
    return sum(matriz[i][i] for i in range(n))
```

O `assert` na função assegurará que a matriz seja quadrada.

A biblioteca NumPy possui a função [`numpy.trace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html) que retorna a soma da diagonal.

Comment: obrigado.......

Answer (score 3):

```
n= 4

m= [[2,6,4,3],[2,4,6,4],[5,1,0,4],[4,5,4,6]]

sum_diagonal = sum(m[i][i]for i in range(n))

print(sum_diagonal)
```